# How to exit `abaqus` command window, after successful analysis of a job submitted, to `Matlab` script when called from `Matlab`

Tags: windows, matlab, abaqus

I called `abaqus` command from Matlab and ran (submitted) a job by:

```
dos(['"C:\Package\Intel\Composer XE 2011 SP1\bin\ifortvars.bat" intel64 && C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /k abaqus job=chaboche1job input=chaboche1job user=chaboche1 interactive'])
```

After successful completion, it does not automatically close the `abaqus` command and get back to `Matlab` script. I have to manually type 'exit'. Can it be done automatically not involving the user?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We're willing to help you. Please take the time to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read up on [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55190690/edit) the question accordingly. Please create [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and give sample inputs, outputs and the error messages you get, if any. This will help us to determine what is going on and improve your chances to get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You explicitly use `cmd.exe /k`, the `/k` flag tells the CMD program to stay open after the program finishes.

Replacing the `/k` flag with a `/c` flag should fix your problem.

See a reference to the `cmd.exe` program [here](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html).

Comment: thanks for the tip, I have found another: https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/20573-close-terminal-window